# When are notifications generated?

Tags: discussion

I know that, for example, the person that asks a question will be notified when an answer is submitted.  Is there a comprehensive list of all events that will trigger a notification (and who will receive the notification)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Comments** - those who are mentioned with `@username` are notified. In case there is a discussion between two users only, the other user is notified without @-mentioning him. The owner of a post is always notified.
- **Answers** - the user who asked the question is always notified of answers.
- **Chat messages** - when a user is mentioned in Chat, and *not* currently active in a room, they are notified. This is when the mentioned user was either recently in chat or notified by the @@ syntax available to moderators.

Comment: Can you indicate exactly who receives the notification in these cases?

Comment: @FooBah: edited just now